# re-write a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an application that uses `devise`.

I want to re-write the new method of the `devise`.

so I create a new controller, is called: UserSessions.

after the login, I want to redirect to google. so I tried:

```
class UserSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def new
       super if defined?(super)
       self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
       clean_up_passwords(resource)

       respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to("http://www.google.com") }
       end
    end
end
```

I ran my app and login to an account, but I wasn't redirected to google, but my site.

I think my changes of the new method are not performed.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to override the create method, not the new method